# anchor tag selection pressing up and down arrow

Tags: jquery, anchor

I want to select the anchor tags when i press on up and down arrows.

here is my code

```
 var keyindex,alinks;
    keyindex = -1;
    $('#ajax_response').keydown(function(e)
        {
            alinks = $('#ajax_response').find('a');
            if(e.keyCode == 40)
            {
                e.preventDefault();     
                if(keyindex == -1)
                {
                keyindex = 1;
                }
                if(alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length)
                {
                $('#ajax_response').find('a')[keyindex++].focus();
                }
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 38)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                if(keyindex == alinks.length)
                {
                keyindex = keyindex-2;
                }

                if(alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length && keyindex >=0)
                {
                $('#ajax_response').find('a')[keyindex--].focus();
                }
            }
        });
```

But sometimes it doesn't work properly .can anybody find the issue in this code please let me know.

Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/rz550dwa/

Comment: What is the `keyindex` here? Where it is declared?

Comment: Show us your HTML, or better, if you create a jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this more dynamic and efficient by

1. Caching the jQuery object containing the links so you don't need to search for them every time.
2. Using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) to dynamically find the currently focussed element, rather than having to track it yourself.

This means it will keep working correctly if one of the links is manually focussed/clicked by the user.

If you want to make it cyclic, you just need the extra `else` statement. Otherwise remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alinks = $('#ajax_response').find('a');
    if(alinks.length > 0) {
        alinks.first().focus();
        $('#ajax_response').keydown(function(e)
        {
            // get the index of the current focussed a 
            var keyIndex = alinks.index(alinks.filter(':focus'));
            if(e.keyCode == 40)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                // find the next index to highlight
                if(keyIndex < 0) {
                    keyIndex = 0;
                } else if(keyIndex < alinks.length - 1) {
                    keyIndex++;
                } else {
                    keyIndex = 0; // for cyclic behaviour
                }
                alinks.eq(keyIndex).focus();
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 38)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                // find the previous index to highlight
                if(keyIndex > alinks.length -1) {
                    keyIndex = alinks.length -1;
                } else if(keyIndex > 0) {
                    keyIndex--;
                } else {
                    keyIndex = alinks.length -1; // for cyclic behaviour
                }
                alinks.eq(keyIndex).focus();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rz550dwa/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

## [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz550dwa/7/)

Set your focus on the first `anchor` element.

To do so replace this line:

```
$('#ajax_response a').focus();
```

With:

```
$('#ajax_response a:eq(0)').focus();
```

## Update

if you click on link the behavior changes. You can fix it with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ajax_response a:eq(0)').focus();
    var keyindex, alinks;
    keyindex = -1;
    // Key Events
    $('#ajax_response').keydown(function (e) {
        alinks = $('#ajax_response').find('a');
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (keyindex == -1) {
                keyindex = 1;
            }
            if (alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length) {
                $('#ajax_response').find('a')[keyindex++].focus();
            }
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (keyindex == alinks.length) {
                keyindex = keyindex - 2;
            }

            if (alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length && keyindex >= 0) {
                $('#ajax_response').find('a')[keyindex--].focus();
            }
        }
    });
    $('#ajax_response a').on("click", function (e) {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        keyindex = index+1;
        console.log(index);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solved in the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rz550dwa/5/

This will work in cyclic fashion!

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var IndexNumber=1;
    function focusAnchor(index){
    $('#ajax_response').find('a')[index].focus();
    };
    $('#ajax_response a').focus();
    // Key Events
    $('#ajax_response').keydown(function(e)
    {
        alinks = $('#ajax_response').find('a');
        if(e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            if(IndexNumber<(alinks.length-1)){
            IndexNumber++;
                focusAnchor(IndexNumber);
            }
            else{
                IndexNumber=0;
                focusAnchor(IndexNumber);
            }
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(IndexNumber>0){
            IndexNumber--;
                focusAnchor(IndexNumber);
            }
            else{
                IndexNumber=alinks.length-1;
                focusAnchor(IndexNumber);
            }
        }
    });
});
```